# Objective-C check if item exists in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this section of code here:

```
for (int i = 0; i<[taskData count]; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<[allJobTaskArray count]; j++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d", i);
            NSLog(@"%d", j);
            PunchListDataCell *pldCell = [[[PunchListDataCell alloc]init] autorelease];
            pldCell.stringData= [self reverseStringDate:[[[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:10]];
            pldCell.cellSelected = NO;
            [punchListData addObject:pldCell];
        }

    }
```

Now let me explain:

- taskData count is 57 and is a NSArray
- allJobTaskArray count is 12 and is a NSMutableArray
- This code will crash at this line: `pldCell.stringData= [self reverseStringDate:[[[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:10]];` when `j` is 6 and `i` is 36 simple because in `allJobTaskArray` objectAtIndex: 6 objectAtIndex: 36 does not exist.
- This is the error I am getting: `[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (36) beyond bounds (36)`
- What I am trying to do is if the item does not exist, then `pldCell` should equal `@""`;

  - My question is how would I check if I am item exist or not ?

I have tried the following:

```
if([[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNull null]){
                pldCell.stringData = @"";
            }else{
                pldCell.stringData= [self reverseStringDate:[[[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:10]];
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altogether it should look something like -

```
for (int i = 0; i<[taskData count]; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<[allJobTaskArray count]; j++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d", i);
            NSLog(@"%d", j);


            PunchListDataCell *pldCell = [[[PunchListDataCell alloc]init] autorelease];
            if ([[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] count] > i) {                    
                pldCell.stringData= [self reverseStringDate:[[[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:10]];
            } else {
                pldCell.stringData = @"";
            }

            pldCell.cellSelected = NO;
            [punchListData addObject:pldCell];
        }
    }
```

Comment: nope, still crashes, it always goes into the else I added which is `pldCell.stringData= [self reverseStringDate:[[[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:10]];`

Comment: It should actually be `>= i`, sorry @user979331

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code? I updated my answer with the complete loops @user979331

Comment: Turns out this works...I just had `pldCell.stringData= [self reverseStringDate:[[[allJobTaskArray objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:10]];` before the condition.